# How to use return object of Mono without using block()?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to learn spring webflux. In `ReactiveMongoRepository`, I am trying to check if category already exists. If it already exists then return that object otherwise save and return new saved object. Something like following.

```
public Mono<Category> save(Category category) {
    final Mono<Category> byId = repository.findById(category.getId());
    final Category block = byId.block();
    if (block == null) {
        return repository.save(new Category(category.getName()));
    } else {
        return byId;
    }
}
```

How can I do this without using `block()`?

Comment: Use `switchIfEmtpy` instead of `block`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Mono::switchIfEmpty`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#switchIfEmpty-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-) that provides an alternative `Mono` in case the former one is completed without data. As long as `ReactiveMongoRepository::save` returns `Mono`, you can pass it to generate the alternative one.

```
return repository.findById(category.getId())
                 .switchIfEmpty(repository.save(new Category(category.getName())));
```

In case `ReactiveMongoRepository::findById` returns a `Mono` with data, the `Mono::switchIfEmpty` will not be called.

**Edit:** Using [`Mono::defer`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#defer-java.util.function.Supplier-) with a `Supplier<Mono>` makes the saving operation to be delayed when necessary:

```
.switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> repository.save(new Category(category.getName()))));
```

Comment: This is not totally correct. respository.save will be called eagerly.

Comment: Yes. The `Mono` with the result is returned immediately upon calling the `save` method and using `Mono::defer` should help. The question was about using avoiding `block()` operation. However, a good point!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
public Mono<Category> getCategories(Category category) {
   return repository.findByName(category.getName()).doOnNext(o -> {
   }).switchIfEmpty(repository.save(category));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to defer the `switchIfEmpty`. Otherwise, it'll be triggered eagerly:

```
return repository.findById(category.getId())
                 .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() ->respository.save(category)));
```